# Show that an extension is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field with $\operatorname{char} K=p$, where $p$ is a prime, and let the degree of the extension $K \leq L$ be coprime to $p$.

How can I show that the extension is separable??

Could you give me some hints??

Comment: Write your extension as a tower of a separable and purely inseparable one.

Comment: @AdamHughes How could I do that?? Could you give me some hints??

Comment: You know a polynomial is inseparable if it has a derivative of $0$, i.e. if it is of the form $g(x^{p^d})$ with $g'(x)\ne 0$ and some $d>0$. That expression with $g$ is how you can write it as a tower.

Comment: @AdamHughes Could you explain to me why it stands that a polynomial is inseparable when it is of the form $g(x^{p^d})$ with $g'(x) \neq 0$ ??

Comment: That is the only way to have a zero derivative

Comment: @AdamHughes So,  does it stand that either $f(x)$ is separable or it is of the form $f(x)=g(x^{p^d})$ ??

Comment: Assuming irreducibility, yes.

Comment: @AdamHughes Ahaa... Ok!! Could you explain to me why we have to write the extension as a tower of a separable and purely inseparable one ??

Comment: If $f$ is inseparable its degree is a multiple of $p$. Field extension towers are multiplicative for degrees.

Comment: @AdamHughes So, let $a \in L$ a root of $f(x)=g(x^{p^d})$. Then $[L:K]=[L:K(a)][K(a):K]$. Since $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K$ and $a$ is a root of $f$, we have that $[K(a):K]= \deg f$. But which is $\deg f$ ??

Comment: By definition it's $p^d\cdot\deg g$.

Comment: @AdamHughes It is as followed: When $$g(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots + a_n x^n$$ then $$f(x)=g(x^{p^d})=a_0+a_1x^{p^d}+\dots + a_n (x^{p^d})^n=a_0+a_1x^{p^d}+\dots + a_n x^{np^d}$$ so $$\deg f=n\cdot p^d=\deg g \cdot p^d$$

right??

Comment: @AdamHughes So, that means that $p \mid [K(a):K] \Rightarrow p \mid [L:K]$. But we know that $([L:K], p)=1$. So, we have a contradiction, right?? At the beginning we have supposed that the extension is not separable, right?? Which means that there is an element $a$ in $L$ which is not separable. And that means that $Irr(a, K)$ is not separable. And since $Irr(a, K)=f(x)$, we have that $f(x)$ is not separable, and that's why it can be written in the form $f(x)=g(x^{p^d})$. Is this correct??

Comment: Yes, that's accurate.

Comment: @AdamHughes Great!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for a field $K$ we have $char(k)=p$ and $f\in K[x]$ is monic and irreducible, then $f$ is separable or there exists a separable polynomial $g\in K[x]$ such that there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ with $f(x)=g(x^{p^n})$. Suppose this is the case for the minimal polynomial of some $\alpha\in L$,then de degree of this polynomial is divisible by $p$, so $[L:K]=[L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$ is divisible by $p$ which is a contradiction, because you assumed that the degree of the extension was coprime with $p$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** What can you say about the degree of the minimal polynomial of a non-separable element?

Comment: Do you mean the following??
$$Irr(a,K) \text{ is separable } \Rightarrow [K(a):K]_{\text{sep}}=[K(a):K]$$

Comment: @MaryStar Not really. If an irreducible polynomial $f$ over a field of characteristic $p>0$ has multiple roots it is of the form $f(x)=g(x^p)$. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial.) Hence $\deg f$ is a multiple of $p$.